# Global.ascx function to detect authenticated users first page visit

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, session-cookies, global-asax

I'm currently using the "Session_Start" function within the Global.ascx file to save when an authenticated user visits my site.

This works OK if a users session expires, however as I'm using persistent cookies the user may return to the site within 28 days and this function will not be called and therefore will not be recording in the database that the user has visited.

I've taken a good look at all the functions available within Global.ascx, however I cannot find one that will perform what I need.

Application_Start - triggered only run within life cycle
Application_BeginRequest - each and every request made
Application_AuthenticateRequest  - each and every request
Session_Start  - when a new session is started

The two events that I believe could be used are Application_BeginRequest or Application_AuthenticateRequest.

Is there any way of limiting the above events to only run specific code on the first visit to a site and not on each request?

Alternatively is there any way of using my master file?

Any suggestions would be very useful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implemented by your own? As you mentioned there is an event Application_BeginRequest. I think following might do the trick:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    string session_param_name = "SOME_SESSION_ID";        

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[session_param_name] == null)
    {
         //Count
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[session_param_name] == null)
    {
        //Also count
     }
}
```

Comment: So when a auth user first visits the site, say example.com there will not be any Request.Form or Request.Querystring variables.